# Make bootstrap "dropdown" expand to the side of the button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a site using the Bootstrap (3.2.0) and I have a button on my page that I'd like to trigger a "dropdown" menu style effect however instead of having the menu expand downward from the button I'd like it to slide out of the right side. The "dropdown" menu items would still be stacked vertically just like normal but instead of having the top of the menu connected to the bottom of the button, the upper-left side of the menu would be connected to the upper-right side of the button.

Comment: As the `.dropdown-menu` already uses absolute positioning, creating a modifier class like `.dropdown-menu-right` and styling it like `.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right { left: 100%; top: 0; }` might be a start.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a great idea is an example of a side by side nav,  i found on the net. http://www.bootply.com/uBVgiR9DDd

```
.dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    width: 400px;
}

.dropdown-menu.multi-column .dropdown-menu {
    display: block !important;
    position: static !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

<ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown"> <a class="" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Heading</a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="" href="#">Col 1 - Opt 1</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a class="" href="#">Col 1 - Opt 2</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="" href="#">Col 2 - Opt 1</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a class="" href="#">Col 2 - Opt 2</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```